# How to get the master server public key in Google Container Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get the master server public key from a Google Container Engine managed Kubernetes cluster.

I have a question about the glcoud beta container clusters describe command

> gcloud beta container clusters describe NAME

The documentation is a currently a bit sparse https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/clusters/describe

Does the "gcloud beta container clusters describe" command return the master server public key? Is that in the masterAuth:clientKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you're looking for is [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters#MasterAuth). `clientKey` is the private key used by clients to authenticate to the master. The `clusterCaCertificate` is the root of trust for the cluster, with which the master's certificate is signed. The API doesn't directly expose the master's public cert, only the root cert.